# Extension of an involution on $G$ to an involution on $G_\mathbb{C}$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, involutions

I asked this question on MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475382/extension-of-an-involution-on-g-to-an-involution-on-g-mathbbc but didn't receive any answer so far. My question is the following:

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group and  $ \sigma :G \rightarrow G $ be an involution on $G$. Let $G^\sigma :=\lbrace g \in G, \sigma(g)=g \rbrace$.

Denote by $G_\mathbb{C}$ the complexification of $G$. Does there exist an involution $\tilde{\sigma}$ on $G_\mathbb{C}$ which coïncides with $\sigma$ on $G$ and such that ${(G^{\sigma})}_\mathbb{C} = {(G_\mathbb{C})}^\tilde{\sigma}$ ?

My though was to define $\tilde{\sigma}$ to be $\sigma$ on G and to be the identity on  the complement of $G$ on $G_\mathbb{C}$, but don't see whether this imply the ${(G^{\sigma})}_\mathbb{C} = {(G_\mathbb{C})}^\tilde{\sigma}$ or not, any help please!

Comment: You should add a cross-reference to your question on MSE, and also in MSE to MO.

Comment: First you need a definition of the complexification of a  compact real *Lie group* $G$. See Serre, Galois Cohomology, Section III.4.5.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, thanks for your comments! Unfortunately I can't access to this reference since it's not free online. The definition of the complexification of a compact connected real Lie group $G$ is that it is a Lie group $G_\mathbb{C}$ which contains $G$ and such that its Lie algebra is the complexification of the Lie algebra of $G$.

Comment: Your group $G^\sigma$ might be nonconnected. For example, take $G=T$, a one-dimensional compact  real torus, and take $\sigma(t)=t^{-1}$ for $t\in T$.

Comment: The correspondence $G\leadsto G_{\Bbb C}$ is a functor, and an involution $\sigma$ of $G$ induces an involution of $G_{\Bbb C}$ (I denote it again by $\sigma$).

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, could you please explain why ${(Lie (G_\mathbb{C}))}^\sigma = {({(LieG)}^\sigma)}_\mathbb{C}$ ? I didn't get it.

Comment: If $G^\sigma$ is connected, then, since $${\rm Lie}\big((G_{\Bbb C})^\sigma\big)=\big({\rm Lie}(G_{\Bbb C})\big)^\sigma
=\big(({\rm Lie}\, G)^\sigma\big)_{\Bbb C}=\big({\rm Lie}(G^\sigma)\big)_{\Bbb C}, $$ the complexification of $G^\sigma$ is $(G_{\Bbb C})^\sigma$.

Comment: The equality $\big({\rm Lie}(G_{\Bbb C})\big)^\sigma=\big(({\rm Lie}\, G)^\sigma\big)_{\Bbb C}$ follows from the fact the the involutive automorphism $(d\sigma)_{\Bbb C}$ of ${\rm Lie}(G_{\Bbb C})$ is the complexification of the involutive automorphism $d\sigma$ of ${\rm Lie}\, G$.

Comment: Anyway, you need the definition of the complexification of Borel and Serre in terms of algebraic groups. An alternative reference is [the paper of Borel and Serre "Théorèmes de finitude..."](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02566948.pdf), Section 6.7, but it is not for free either.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, I actually Find this reference and it is for Free, thanks a lot for pointing this out !

Comment: I think that I understand a lot of  what you  have explained (even though I have  to work it on more details ). Maybe last question: What we can do in case $G^\sigma$ is not connected ?

Comment: I think that you need to prove that any connected component of $(G_{\Bbb C})^\sigma$ contains a point of $G^\sigma$. I cannot do that now.

Comment: No problem!  Your comments were of a great help, thank you very much :)

Comment: The connected compact groups (like $G$) have been classified, and their involutions have been classified too (for semisimple compact groups by Elie Cartan, Victor Kac, and others).  Instead of *proving* this, you can *compute* $(G_{\Bbb C})^\sigma$ and $G^\sigma$, and check the above assertion about the points in connected components.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, your comments have answered my question, so thanks a lot! If you don't mind, you could collect them in the answer section in MSE, I'll accept your answer and offer the bounty .

Comment: I have answered your question only in the case when $G^\sigma$ is connected. Therefore, let the comments remain comments.